# inserting date in table in a format like "dd.mm.yyyy"

Tags: mysql, date

I've tried to figure out how could I insert dates in my table,say,table3 in a format like "12.04.2013". When I write :

```
create table3(
UserID varchar(255),
Date DATE,
primary key(UserID);
```

I have to give date  "DD-MM-YYYY" format but my date string'll be like "DD.MM.YYYY".

Is there anyone to help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to provide the date as YYYY-MM-DD. See STR_TO_DATE() and DATE_FORMAT()

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d.%m.%Y')` will result in `11.11.2013`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `DD.MM.YYYY` format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) is not a valid date format.  You should use `YYYY-MM-DD` for storage purposes.  Changing between these is very easy though.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d.%m.%Y')
```